# iPhone objects not sizing correctly on different devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

So I'm building an application that has different objects on the ViewController. When I run in on the iPhone 5/5s it runs nicely, whereas on the 6 and 6 Plus it looks very messed up. I used to know how to make it work on all devices, I just can't figure it out anymore. Can anyone help me please?

Here are photos for more explanation:

6 Plus:

[image: 6 Plus]

5s:

[image: 5s]

Please help, I'm new to this and I'd like a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select both objects then add the following constraints:

[image: one]

and after that:

[image: two]

That should keep the textfield and button in the center on all devices.

Comment: I can't find constraints in the Xcode 6, used to be there in Xcode 5:
http://imgur.com/904K88X

Please point it out to me. Also if it is important, I'm not using auto-layout cause I don't know how that works.

Comment: Is auto-layout turned off? Select a ViewController go to your File Inspector and turn auto-layout on to use constraints.

Comment: Wouldn't auto-layout mess my whole app design? All could you explain auto-layout?

Comment: Auto-layout enables constraints so you can make one storyboard that looks good on all devices with different sizes. It is the course Apple wants developers to take. It also ensures your app will look great on future devices with different sizes without having to upgrade them with new versions all the time.